# Typescript: extending IterableIterator for array type but return a simple type

Tags: arrays, typescript, generics

I am trying to extend the `IterableIterator` with a method similar to `Array.flat()`. Writing the method itself is no problem, extending the interface for `IterableIterator` is also easy. So the javascript part is under control. Unfortunately I can't get the typescript compiler to understand what I want.

How should I declare Flatten in IterableIterator for item to be understood by typescript as a `number` and not as a `number[]` like it is now?

[image]

NOTE: if I wrap `total+=item` with `if(item instanceof number) {}` the method works. Just for completion the method looks currently like this:

```
function* iterable_flatten<T>(this: Iterable<T[]>): Generator<T> {
    for (let item of this) {
        for (let itemitem of item)
            yield itemitem;
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you extend IterableIterator? Could you explain how do you define the iterable_flatten method on the prototype? I can't find a way to do that.

Comment: Maybe you can create a new question for this. The comments are really not really suitable for answering other questions with code samples and further comments

Comment: You are right, I have created another thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66843182/how-to-extend-iterableiterator-in-typescript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading [this article](https://medium.com/@tar.viturawong/the-true-power-of-typescript-generics-1303d78a1c9a) I found out that the solution is to create a type which infers the base type of the array :

```
type BaseTypeOfArray<T> = T extends Array<infer I> ? I : "never";
```

And then use it to get the base type in the declaration:

```
flatten(this: Iterable<T>): Generator<BaseTypeOfArray<T>>;
```