# How to extend IterableIterator in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am trying to extend `Iterable` with a where method, similar to C# `Enumerable.where()`. Extending the `Array` prototype is easy, however I am struggling to find how to extend an `Iterable`.

Here is the declaration:

```
declare interface Iterable<T> {
    where<T>(this: Iterable<T>, predicate: (item: T) => boolean): Generator<T>;
}
```

Problem is with the implementation. The extended method compiles just fine, but at runtime when trying to use that method on an `Array` (which is an `Iterable`) or any `Iterable`, it will throw that `where()` isn't defined. On `Array` you would just add the method implementation to `Array.prototype`, but `Iterable` has no prototype:

```
function* where<T>(this: Iterable<T>, predicate: (item: T) => boolean): Generator<T> {
    for (const item of this) {
        if (predicate(item)) {
            yield item;
        }
    }
}
```

`Iterable.prototype = function* where(...)` does not work because `Iterable` has no prototype.

Here is the desired usage:

```
public myMethod(myIterable: Iterable<number> ) {
    console.log(myIterable.where(i => i > 3));
}
```

How do I extend `Iterable`? Should I be extending `IterableIterator` instead?

Someone has managed to do it another thread ([https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62008192/typescript-`extending`-iterableiterator-for-array-type-but-return-a-simple-type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62008192/typescript-%60extending%60-iterableiterator-for-array-type-but-return-a-simple-type)) but he doesn't show how he extends Iterable and told me to ask another question.

Comment: Each iterable implements its own iterator by design so that each custom iterator can accommodate the unique structure of the interable. Providing generic functionality then breaks the design concept. So, there is no "Iterable" interface or object available to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can extend the [`IteratorPrototype`](https://262.ecma-international.org/11.0/#sec-%iteratorprototype%-object) in which case your method will work with built-in Iterators like `array.keys()` or star functions, but not Iterables like arrays.

As you correctly said, there's no way to extend `Iterable` because no such thing exists at run time. Generally speaking, a more common practice is to design your own "monad" instead of extending built-in prototypes:

```
result = Enumerable(someIterable)
    .where(...)
    .map(...)
    .etc(...)
    .toList()
```

Comment: Yes, that is what I came to a conclusion; make my own Enumerable class. Thanks